# How to generate a unique hash code for an object, based on its contents?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, hash

I need to generate a unique hash code for an object, based on its contents, e.g. DateTime(2011,06,04) should equal DateTime(2011,06,04).

- I cannot use .GetHashCode() because it might generate the same hash code for objects with different contents.
- I cannot use .GetID from ObjectIDGenerator as it generates a different hash code for objects with the same contents.
- If the object contains other sub-objects, it needs to recursively check these.
- It needs to work on collections.

The reason I need to write this? I'm writing a caching layer using PostSharp.

**Update**

I think I may have been asking the wrong question. As Jon Skeet pointed out, to be on the safe side, I need as many unique combinations in the cache key as there are combinations of potential data in the object. Therefore, the best solution might be to build up a long string that encodes the public properties for the object, using reflection. The objects are not too large so this is very quick and efficient:

- Its efficient to construct the cache key (just convert the public properties of the object into a big string).
- Its efficient to check for a cache hit (compare two strings).

Comment: When you say 'contents' what exactly do you mean? Public properties? Something else?

Comment: You are saying that you want a value guaranteed to be unique and to change if anything in the object or its aggregates changes. Do you realize this means that you want to compress a possibly infinite amount of information into a finite-length data structure?

Comment: I'd like something like a GUID based on the objects contents. I don't mind if there's the occasional duplicate every 10 trillion trillion trillion years or so.

Comment: @Gravitas: My "infinity" comment means that you 'd have a hard time incorporating an `IEnumerable` like this into the hash: `while(true) yield return 1;`.

Comment: Serialize object to String and then get MD5 of the string value.
The only problem is [Serializable] attribute.

Comment: @Gravitas, what was your final solution to this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you need to create a *unique* hash code, then you're basically talking about a number which can represent as many states as your type can have. For `DateTime` than means taking the Ticks value and the `DateTimeKind`, I believe.

You may be able to get away with assuming that the top two bits of the `Ticks` property are going to be zero, and using those to store the kind. That means you're okay up until the year 7307 as far as I can tell:

```
private static ulong Hash(DateTime when)
{
    ulong kind = (ulong) (int) when.Kind;
    return (kind << 62) | (ulong) when.Ticks;
}
```

Comment: Wow, incredibly fast answer. However, I need a unique value for any object, not just DateTime. And, on further thought, I don't mind if the odd object returns the same hash code, as I don't mind the occasional cache miss.

Comment: @Gravitas: You haven't specified how big your hash code can be. I've given a sample for DateTime which will be unique and will work for a pretty wide range of values... but it gives a 64 bit value. If you need a 32 bit value, we'll need to take a different approach.

Comment: Off-topic, but for what it's worth you can use the built-in [`ToBinary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tobinary.aspx) and [`FromBinary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.frombinary.aspx) methods to serialise/deserialise between `DateTime` and `long` (encapsulating both `Kind` and `Ticks`).

Comment: how would you get a 32 bit value?

Answer (score 39):

From a comment:

> I'd like something like a GUID based on the objects contents. I don't mind if there's the occasional duplicate every 10 trillion trillion trillion years or so

That seems like an unusual requirement but since that's your requirement, let's do the math.

Let's suppose you make a billion unique objects a year -- thirty per second -- for 10 trillion trillion trillion years. That's 10<sup>49</sup> unique objects you're creating. Working out the math is quite easy; **the probability of at least one hash collision in that time is above one in 10<sup>18</sup> when the bit size of the hash is less than 384.**

Therefore you'll need at least a 384 bit hash code to have the level of uniqueness that you require. That's a convenient size, being 12 int32s. If you're going to be making more than 30 objects a second or want the probability to be less than one in 10<sup>18</sup> then more bits will be necessary.

Why do you have such stringent requirements?

Here's what I would do if I had your stated requirements. The first problem is to convert every possible datum into a self-describing sequence of bits. If you have a serialization format already, use that. If not, invent one that can serialize all possible objects that you are interested in hashing.

Then, to hash the object, serialize it into a byte array and then run the byte array through the SHA-384 or SHA-512 hashing algorithm.  That will produce a professional-crypto-grade 384 or 512 bit hash that is believed to be unique even in the face of attackers trying to force collisions. That many bits should be more than enough to ensure low probability of collision in your ten trillion trillion trillion year timeframe.

Answer (score 12):

You are not talking about a hash code here, you need a number representation of your state - for that to be unique it might have to be incredibly large depending on your object structure.

> The reason I need to write this? I'm
>   writing a caching layer using
>   PostSharp.

Why don't you use a regular hashcode instead, and handle collisions by actually comparing the objects? That seems to be the most reasonable approach.

Comment: Beat me to it. :) The problem isn't solvable with some super hash code. Use a more normal hash code and when it finds a match, use something Equals() to check if they're really the same thing.

Comment: You're actually right: I could probably use .GetHashCode, as I don't really mind if there's the occasional cache miss.

Comment: +1: this is of course the solution, and what the .NET hash-based containers do.

Comment: @Gravitas: The definition of `GetHashCode` ensures that you will never have a problem with false *negatives*. It's false *positives* that you have to watch out for.

Comment: @Jon - yes, you're right: I really don't want an incorrect answer to be returned for a different set of parameters. Back to the drawing board - I really need something like a GUID based on the objects contents.

Comment: I'm not sure how I could handle collisions by comparing the objects - in PostSharp, you have to compress everything down to a string as the cache key. The objects themselves are not saved.

Comment: @Gravitas - based on the cache key how do you retrieve the actual object then? Or would you retrieve the object if you didn't have the caching layer?

Answer (score 4):

An addition to BrokenGlass' answer, which I have voted up and consider to be correct:

Using the `GetHashCode`/`Equals` method means that if two objects hash to the same value you 'll be relying in their `Equals` implementation to tell you if they are equivalent.

Unless these objects override `Equals` (which would practically mean that they implement `IEquatable<T>` where `T` is their type), the default implementation of `Equals` is going to do a reference comparison. This in turn means that *your cache would mistakenly yield a miss* for objects which are "equal" in the business sense but have been constructed independently.

**Consider the usage model for your cache carefully**, because if you end up using it for classes that are not `IEquatable` and in a manner where you expect to be checking non-reference-equal objects for equality, the cache will turn out to be *completely useless*.

Answer (score 3):

> I cannot use .GetHashCode() because it might generate the same hash code for objects with different contents.

It's quite normal for a hash code to have collisions.  If your hash code has a fixed length (32 bits in the case of the standard .NET hash code), then you're bound to have collisions with any values whose range is bigger than this (e.g. 64 bits for long; n*64 bits for an array of n longs etc).

In fact for any hash code with a finite length N, there will always be collisions for collections of more than N elements.

What you're asking for isn't feasible in the general case.

Comment: Can you explain why this is unfeasible?  The entire public key infrastructure that underlies the web security model depends on this problem having a feasible solution; since there is such an infrastructure, that's evidence that a feasible, low-cost solution exists. It is quite normal (as you correctly note) for a 32 bit hash code to have collisions, but extremely rare to the point of impossibility for a 128 bit hash code to have accidental collisions. The fact that obviously there are more than 2^128 possible strings is irrelevant; it's a big space compared to the number of documents hashed.

Comment: Also, I think your math is a bit off there. I think you meant to say "in fact, for any hash code with finite length of n bits, there will be collisions for collections of more than 2^n elements". Right? (And more to the point, the probability of a collision happening becomes *very* large when there are more than 2^(n/2) elements)

Answer (score 3):

We had exactly the same requirement and here is the function I came up with. This is what works well for types of objects we need to cache

```
public static string CreateCacheKey(this object obj, string propName = null)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    if (obj.GetType().IsValueType || obj is string)
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}_{1}|", propName, obj);
    else
        foreach (var prop in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            if (typeof(IEnumerable<object>).IsAssignableFrom(prop.PropertyType))
            {
                var get = prop.GetGetMethod();
                if (!get.IsStatic && get.GetParameters().Length == 0)
                {
                    var collection = (IEnumerable<object>)get.Invoke(obj, null);
                    if (collection != null)
                        foreach (var o in collection)
                            sb.Append(o.CreateCacheKey(prop.Name));
                }
            }
            else
                sb.AppendFormat("{0}{1}_{2}|", propName, prop.Name, prop.GetValue(obj, null));

        }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

So for example if we have something like this

```
var bar = new Bar()
{
    PropString = "test string",
    PropInt = 9,
    PropBool = true,
    PropListString = new List<string>() {"list string 1", "list string 2"},
    PropListFoo =
        new List<Foo>()
            {new Foo() {PropString = "foo 1 string"}, new Foo() {PropString = "foo 2 string"}},
    PropListTuple =
        new List<Tuple<string, int>>()
            {
                new Tuple<string, int>("tuple 1 string", 1), new Tuple<string, int>("tuple 2 string", 2)
            }
};

var cacheKey = bar.CreateCacheKey();
```

Cache key generated by method above will be

> PropString_test string|PropInt_9|PropBool_True|PropListString_list string 1|PropListString_list string 2|PropListFooPropString_foo 1 string|PropListFooPropString_foo 2 string|PropListTupleItem1_tuple 1 string|PropListTupleItem2_1|PropListTupleItem1_tuple 2 string|PropListTupleItem2_2|

Comment: I get a TargetParameterCountException for Item in List (thrown from line with AppensFormat"{0}{1}_{2}|)

Answer (score 3):

You can calculate ex md5 sum (or something like that) from object serialized to json.
If you want only some properties to matter, you can create anonymous object on the way:

```
 public static string GetChecksum(this YourClass obj)
    {
        var copy = new
        {
           obj.Prop1,
           obj.Prop2
        };
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ob);

        return json.CalculateMD5Hash();
    }
```

I use that for checking if someone messed with my database storing license based data. You can also append json variable with some seed to complicate stuff

Comment: Considering this is both an old question and a question that has multiple good answers as well as clarification from the OP about what the requirements was then your answers falls prey to the test of time. Your answer is only going to be good up to objects of a maximum of 128 bits, or 16 bytes, which is hardly a general solution. In lieu of the clarification in the bottom of the question, the json string would be more appropriate than its MD5 checksum.

Comment: I mean, it does EXACTLY what OP meant: gets unique hash code of object, that changes when properties change, and is same for two different instances with same properties values. MD5 sum is only for constant length, even for collections.

Could you elaborate thy json itself would be better?

EDIT: ok, i get it :) but still, longer hash from json can be a valid way to go

Answer (score 1):

Would this extension method suit your purposes? If the object is a value type, it just returns its hash code. Otherwise, it recursively gets the value of each property and combines them into a single hash.

```
using System.Reflection;

public static class HashCode
{
    public static ulong CreateHashCode(this object obj)
    {
        ulong hash = 0;
        Type objType = obj.GetType();

        if (objType.IsValueType || obj is string)
        {
            unchecked
            {
                hash = (uint)obj.GetHashCode() * 397;
            }

            return hash;
        }

        unchecked
        {
            foreach (PropertyInfo property in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                object value = property.GetValue(obj, null);
                hash ^= value.CreateHashCode();
            }
        }

        return hash;
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not satisfy the OP's very first requirement, obviously.

Comment: `public class HaHa { public HaHa Recursive { get{ return this;} } }`

Comment: @smartcaveman: good point. It's easy to fix the case where a class has a property that returns itself. But not so easy is where a pair of classes have properties that reference each other.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the answers here serialize to JSON and generate an MD5 hash from that.  This works most the time except when you have collections and the item order is different.  The same object could generate different hashes because of the collection order difference.

The solution I came up with is below where I serialize to JSON (using Newtonsoft Json.NET) and order any child collections by hashing each of the items and sorting by that hash.  This gives us a deterministic serialized representation we can generate a hash on.

There might be some scenarios I'm not fully accounting for, but this works for the nested collections of complex objects for most common scenarios.

```
static class ObjectHashGenerator
{
    private static readonly OrderedPropertiesContractResolver ContractResolver = new();
    private static readonly OrderedCollectionConverter Converter = new();
    private static readonly IList<JsonConverter> Converters = new List<JsonConverter>(new[] { Converter });
    private static readonly JsonSerializerSettings Settings = new()
    {
        ContractResolver = ContractResolver,
        Converters = Converters
    };
    
    public static string GenerateHash(this object item)
    {
        var serializedItem = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item, Settings);
        var hash = GenerateMd5(serializedItem);
        return hash;
    }

    public static string GenerateMd5(string input)
    {
        using var md5 = MD5.Create();
        var inputBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
        var hashBytes = md5.ComputeHash(inputBytes);
        return Convert.ToHexString(hashBytes);
    }
}

sealed class OrderedPropertiesContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var props = base.CreateProperties(type, memberSerialization);
        return props.OrderBy(p => p.PropertyName).ToList();
    }
}

sealed class OrderedCollectionConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type type)
    {
        if (type == typeof(string)) 
            return false;
        
        return typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(type);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object? value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (value is not IEnumerable enumerable) 
            return;
        
        var itemsJson = new List<string>();
        
        foreach (var item in enumerable)
        {
            var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            using var stringWriter = new StringWriter(stringBuilder);
            serializer.Serialize(stringWriter, item); 
            
            var result = stringBuilder.ToString();
            itemsJson.Add(result);
            stringBuilder.Clear();
        }
        
        // We order each collection by hash of the item so the serialized JSON is deterministically 
        // created so the hash can be the same for objects regardless of collection order on the original.
        writer.WriteStartArray();
        foreach (var item in itemsJson.OrderBy(ObjectHashGenerator.GenerateMd5))
            writer.WriteRawValue(item);
        writer.WriteEndArray();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type type, object? existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        // This converter is only used for serialization in order to generate a hash
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Generic Extension Method**

```
public static class GenericExtensions
{
    public static int GetDeepHashCode<T>(this T obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return 0;

        if (typeof(T).IsValueType)
            return obj.GetHashCode();

        var result = 0;

        if (typeof(T) is IEnumerable)
        {
            var enumerable = obj as IEnumerable<T>;

            using (var enumerator = enumerable.GetEnumerator())
            {
                var i = 1;

                while (true)
                {
                    bool moveNextA = enumerator.MoveNext();

                    if (!moveNextA)
                        break;

                    var current = enumerator.Current;

                    result += current.GetDeepHashCode() * i;

                    i++;
                }

                return result;
            }
        }

        foreach (var property in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            var value = property.GetValue(obj);

            result += value.GetDeepHashCode();
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```